# EventManager - listener raises it's own event - how can i listen to the listeners event?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

As the title suggests, i have a service that scrapes a site, and returns the content through an event.

```
class PageScraper implements EventManagerAwareInterface
{
    //snip - gets page content
     $this->getEventManager()->trigger('scraper.hasContent', $this, ['content' => $scrapedContent]);
}
```

I have several different listeners that do different things to this content (logging, saving, filtering, etc.) so each is in a separate listener.

```
class ScrapePageControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {   
        $pageScraper= $container->get(PageScraper::class);

        $contentSaverListener= $container->get(ContentSaverListener::class);
        $contentSaverListener->attach($pageScraper->getEventManager());

        $contentFilterListener= $container->get(ContentFilterListener::class);
        $contentFilterListener->attach($pageScraper->getEventManager());

        return new ScrapePageController($pageScraper);
    }
}
```

One of these listeners also triggers it's own events:

```
class ContentFilterListener extends AbstractListenerAggregate implements EventManagerAwareInterface
{
   public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events, $priority = 1)
   {
       $this->listeners[] = $events->attach('scraper.hasContent', [$this, 'onFilterContent']);
   }

   public function onFilterContent(Event $event)
   {
        //snip - do some stuff
        if($result->count() == 0){        
            $this->getEventManager()->trigger('contentFilter.empty', $this, ['result' => $result]);
            $event->stopPropagation(true);
            return;
        }

        $event->setParam('filteredContent', $result->getFilteredText());
        $this->getEventManager()->trigger('contentFilter.found', $this, ['result' => $result, 'response' => $response]);
   }
}
```

So, in a controller or service layer, how can i listen to this "inner" event? I would have thought that by sharing the instance of the EM, that all events would be raised and listenable from the PageScraper, ie:

```
 $pageScraper->getEventManager()->attach('contentFilter.found', function($event){
    print_r($event->getParam('filteredContent'));
});
```

...but this event is never caught. The ContentFilterListener's event is triggered and the action is executed, but i can't get the events raised or the event params from the listener.

Comment: With the call to trigger the `contentFilter.found` event (inside `onFilterContent()`) you are passing new arguments  to `trigger()`; the event manager will create a *new* event instance for this new event so `$event->setParam('filteredContent','xx')` would not have been set on it. Instead, you could add to your third argument `['filteredContent' => $result->getFilteredText()]` to make that param part of the new event that gets created.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is actually the desired behaviour: to add the filteredContent param to the *current* event (for other listeners in the chain to add operate on), whilst also triggering *another* event specific to this listener.

Comment: Okay, you might want to update your last code example then - the event listener is being attached to `contentFilter.found`. Based on what you said that attach should be on `scraper.hasContent` instead.

Comment: Ah, but the scraper.hasContent event contains different information (a different event) to the contentFilter.found event. 
Essentially the scraper.hasContent event listener triggers an event with the raw data. The triggering of this event passes this data to each listener that performs some operation on this raw data. Each of these listeners then triggers *its own event with the new/modified data*, which i need to grab.
If i'm in a service or model layer, and listen to the scraper.hasContent event, i will only ever get the raw page data, not the listeners data.